# Why "rsync --exclude-from" ist not working

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

Hi I'm trying to sync local files to a remote server, the files are copied, but the excluded files are not working.

What I want to exlude is some files, under some different folders for example:
htdocs/index.php
htdocs/.htaccess
htdocs/conf/Configuration.php

```
rsync -arvz --no-links --exclude-from 'excluded-files.txt' ./htdocs/ user@host:/var/www/test/htdocs/
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using `-R`, the exclude patterns are matched against the subdirectories of the *from* directory. In your case you must exclude `index.php` rather than `htdocs/index.php`, but that might match too many such files. By adding `-R` instead, the name you will test against will be `./htdocs/...`, so the patterns will work, but you then need to remove `htdocs` from the destination directory, i.e. `user@host:/var/www/test/`